# React State not updating using function updater

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm having trouble figuring out why my React component won't update when I set its state. I'm using the Context API in a Provider pattern, but this happens when I use the `useState` hook as well.

I've tried `useState`, I've tried creating a new object to ensure it's not catching a reference, , and I've stepped through the debugger to ensure the function returns the expected value. But the state just won't update

Here's my code. I'm attaching the state updater to an event listener which fires when a user deletes a component from a wysiwyg editor. The second setLiveComponents works just fine. The first one doesn't.

Would the fact that it's called in a callback change anything? I don't think it would...

```jsx
function App() {
  const [liveComponents, setLiveComponents] = useLiveComponents();

  editor.on("component:add", (component, block) => {
    component.removed = () => {
      setLiveComponents((current) => {
        //This accomplishes the same thing as "delete obj[key]" but creates a new object

        var keepKeys = Object.keys(current).filter(
          (entry) => entry != component.getId()
        );
        var newObj = keepKeys.reduce((obj, key) => {
          obj[key] = current[key];
          return obj;
        }, {});
        return newObj;
      });
    };

    var newObj = {};
    let customComponent = { settings: {}, gjsComponent: component };
    newObj[component.getId()] = customComponent;

    setLiveComponents((liveState) => {
      return { ...liveState, ...newObj };
    });
```

Any ideas would be so helpful. Thanks!

Comment: A good chance you forgot to add `Provider`.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I did add the provider. This issue is also occurring when I use the regular useState pattern as well

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the problem here was the setter was getting passed into another library's event handler, which was running in a different execution context. I had assumed it would pass the setter method properly and execute properly, but no.

The solution was to turn this into a class component and bind the setter to this (this.setter = setter.bind(this))

I'm still not fully clear on the issue with the functional approach. Would love any insight!